# How to access data in MibTableColumn

Tags: python, pysnmp

I need to extract value's name from mib's syntax and I don't know how to do it. When my script receive trap from device with oid "ccmHistoryEventCommandSource" with value "1" I want to get it's name which is "commandLine"...

Part of mib (CISCO-CONFIG-MAN-MIB):

```
ccmHistoryEventCommandSource OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX          INTEGER  {
                        commandLine(1),
                        snmp(2)
                    }
    MAX-ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS          current
    DESCRIPTION
            "The source of the command that instigated the event."
    ::= { ccmHistoryEventEntry 3 }
```

This is part of my code:

```
mib_obj = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(oid).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
mn = mib_obj.getMibNode()
print(">>> ", mn)
print(">>> ", mn.syntax)
```

And this is output:

```
>>>  MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 9, 43, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3), Integer32(subtypeSpec=ConstraintsUnion(ConstraintsUnion(SingleValueConstraint(1, 2)), ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647))), NamedValues(('commandLine', 1), ('snmp', 2))))
>>>  NoValue()
```

I have compiled CISCO-CONFIG-MAN-MIB.py with code:

```
ccmHistoryEventCommandSource = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 9, 43, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3), Integer32().subtype(subtypeSpec=ConstraintsUnion(SingleValueConstraint(1, 2))).clone(namedValues=NamedValues(("commandLine", 1), ("snmp", 2)))).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

As we can see, output has some NamedValues I need, but I don't know how to access this data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ObjectIdentity` object never carries any value, it's just an ID of a MIB object. But  `ObjectType` object accommodates both, the ID and the value.

So you need to feed the variable-bindings you receive in the TRAP message to the [ObjectType](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType) object rather than to the `ObjectIdentity` one.

Perhaps something like this:

```
resolved_var_binds = [
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid), value).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
    for oid, value in var_binds]

resolved_values = [value for oid, value in resolved_varbinds]
```

Make sure you [load the MIB](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.loadMibs) that defines the object you are trying to resolve. You may also need to [configure the source](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource) of the ASN.1 MIBs (or you could pre-compile them and configure their source if you wish).

Comment: Thank you for answer, Ilya. And thank you for pysnmp!